# Loop through list and compare previous line to current line. I have a list of account numbers mostly duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

My result two is a list of account numbers and dates that I have added from another list by using LINQ to sort. The list of result two contains many duplicate account numbers but I would like to filter the list to remove duplicates but not just selecting the first instance.

I am looking to select the account number that has the oldest date. I'm getting some output from the stream reader but its not behaving as expected. I am still getting every line and no removals.

I'm trying to compare if the account number matches the account number from the previous line and the current date is older to remove the instance of the account number with the newer date.

Any ideas?

```cs
    foreach (var valueTwo in resultTwo)
    {
        var valueString = valueTwo.Name.ToString();
        var currentAccount = valueString.Substring(0, valueString.IndexOf('\t'));
        var currentDateTwo = (valueString.Substring((valueString.IndexOf('\t') + 1), 10).Replace("/", ""));
        int currentDate = Convert.ToInt32(currentDateTwo);
        var prevAccount = "";
        int prevDate = 0;

        if (currentAccount != prevAccount)
        {
            forecastTestList.Add(currentAccount + '\t' + currentDate);
        }

        if (currentAccount == prevAccount)
        {
            if (currentDate > prevDate)
            {
                forecastTestList.Remove(prevAccount + '\t' + prevDate);
                forecastTestList.Add(currentAccount + '\t' + currentDate);
            }
        }
        prevAccount = currentAccount;
        prevDate = currentDate;

        //srcheckForecast.WriteLine(valueTwo.Name);
    }

    foreach (var valueThree in forecastTestList)
    {
        srcheckForecast.WriteLine(valueThree);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should initialize `prevAccount`and `prevDate` only once outside the loop.

Comment: And 2 hints: Use `if (a == b) {} else {}` instead of comparing `==` and `!=`. Code would be easier to read and when you sort descending the list by date you don't neeed the inner if.

Comment: Ah of course, hard to compare values when I'm wiping them out each go! Thank you and for the other tips as well!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) data structure to store the maximum day for each account:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var valueTwo in resultTwo)
{
    var valueString = valueTwo.Name.ToString();
    var currentAccount = valueString.Substring(0, valueString.IndexOf('\t'));
    var currentDateTwo = (valueString.Substring((valueString.IndexOf('\t') + 1), 10).Replace("/", ""));
    int currentDate = Convert.ToInt32(currentDateTwo);

    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(currentAccount, out int value) || currentDate > value)
    {
        dictionary[currentAccount] = currentDate;
    }   
}

// transorm dictionary to List<string> of your form
var forecastTestList = dictionary.Select(x => $"{x.Key + '\t' + x.Value}").ToList();
```